# Whether assigning of single precision IEEE754 float to double is reversible?

Tags: floating-point

Using the IEEE754 standard, let's assign single precision variable **s** to double precision variable **d** and then assign **d** to single precision variable **s'**.

Is this operation is reversible (lossless) for any value that can be represented in IEEE754, including NaN, infinity, etc.?  In other words, is it guaranteed that **s** = **s'** for all possible **s**?

---

On my processor NaN is not reversible (01 00 80 7f != 01 00 c0 7f).  Brute force shows that NaN is not reversible, but this might be implementation dependent, so please answer within the scope of IEEE754 standard.

Comment: BTW, yes you can store NaN, -inf and +inf in SQLLite: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview/e06c4caff3c433c80616ae5c6df63fc830825e59

Comment: @Johan - Thank you! I knew this is the correct place to ask this=) This is workaround for me as my DB (I believe ) has one form of NaN. But there are quiet NaN, signaling NaN. They all map to text 'NaN' =)

Answer (score 1):

The value of a number does not change when converting a single to a double.
This includes converting single +/-inf to double +/-inf.

However the printed representation of that number may change, this is the way that number would be printed on screen or converted to a string. 
Let me give you an example.

```
single s;
single s1;
s = 125.32f;
println("value of s = " + s);  --> displays 125.32
double d = s;
println("value of d = " + d);  --> displays 125.31999969482422
```

Does that mean that s ≠ d?
**No:** s does equal d, and when d is assigned to s1, s and s1 will be exactly equal.
The difference in the displayed value is [because more digits are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of the same type.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toString%28%29)
This is a quote from the Java docs, but of course this issue extends to all languages that use IEEE754 floats.

Full disclosure: I copied most of this answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504833/why-converting-from-float-to-double-changes-the-value

See here if you want to hear it from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) himself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504833/why-converting-from-float-to-double-changes-the-value

**Update**
I just tested the assertion using the following code and I can indeed confirm that casting a single to a double and back again does not yield any data loss whatsoever. This was tested in Delphi, but I have no reason to suspect the results would be different in any other IEEE754 compliant environment.

```
var
  a: cardinal;
  s: single absolute a;     //a and s occupy the same memory slot.
  s2: single;
  b: cardinal absolute s2;  //b and s2 occupy the same memory slot.
  d: double;

begin
  for a:= 0 to $FFFFFFFF do begin
    if not(IsNaN(s)) then begin  //must exclude NaN to avoid exceptions.
      d:= s;
      s2:= d;
      assert(a = b);
    end;
  end;
end.
```

The test took 2 minutes of CPU time.

Just to satisfy the OP's curiosity there is no 'algorithm' happening here, the line `d:= s` is compiled as:

```
Project82.dpr.20: d:= s;
00419526 D905CC0E4200     fld dword ptr [$00420ecc]
0041952C DD1DD80E4200     fstp qword ptr [$00420ed8]
```

That means the CPU itself performs the cast. And I do believe we can trust the CPU to be IEEE754 compliant.

Comment: Thank you - these topics about "Why text representation differs". I'm wondering "Whether conversion is reversible" and Why. I see JLS says "float to double" is A widening primitive conversion and widening "does not lose information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value" I trust JLS. But Why it happens? I see binary representation of single and double is not just expansion and truncation. Some algorithm of transformation should exist to make s = s'

Comment: Pi is an example where only part of single's mantissa is substring of double representation (01000000010010010000111111011011 and 0100000000001001001000011111101101010100010001000010110100011000). So, reversion is not simple truncation.

Comment: https://evanw.github.io/float-toy/

Comment: @Kaponir, the simple trucation **does** apply if the extra space is filled with zero's which is what your question was about. If you change the question, then obviously the answer changes as well. If there is non-zero data in the extra space then rounding happens.

Comment: 23-th (least significant) of mantissa's bit of single is 1 and 0 in double

Comment: decimal 0.1 will be in single as 00111101110011001100110011001101 and in double as 0011111110111001100110011001100110100000000000000000000000000000. Mantissa extended by zeros to the right, exponent not only by zeros to the left. So, single binary string is not substring of double (as short integer within integer). But single without leading zeros is substring of double. If exponent had been extended only by zeros then we would have very small number 1 × 2^-900 × 1.600000023841858 (instead of 1 × 2^-4 × 1.600000023841858)

Comment: Note that I tested 0.1 as well. I tested all possible singles, see the code above.

Comment: Literally - you have answered =). But... as my professor said (when I used Maple for finding prime factorization at Number theory labs)  - "we are computer scientists"... I will mark your answer as correct. Thank you.

Comment: this means that hardware implements algorithm - has its microprograms.

Comment: You added final part that is incorrect - please pay attention to my examples with 0.1 and 3.14. and this 
 
evanw.github.io/float-toy

Comment: Uhm, yes the 'algorithm' if you insist on calling it that is hard coded into the silicon. Not in microcode mind you, it's etched into the fixed circuitry. Note that there are different rounding modes, but in all rounding modes the above code delivers the same result.

Comment: I consider IEEE754 standard - without regard to implementation.

Comment: No, Pi-single does not get translated into the pi-double visible on http://evanw.github.io/float-toy  that does not happen. It gets translated to a truncated pi with zero's in it. And PI is not one of the very few special cased IEEE754 floats.

Comment: it's night here - let's talk tomorrow =)

Comment: @Kaponir it can't be that the conversion only pad with zeros. To the very least it needs to pad with the "sitcky bit". I'm quite sure it also uses the guard bit. By the conversion calcs I linked to, the padding is not necessarily a zero.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help. This is not full answer - just information to think.

> 5.3 Floating-Point Format Conversions
>   It shall be possible to convert floating-point numbers between all supported formats. If the conversion is to a narrower
>   precision, the result shall be rounded as specified in Section 4. Conversion to a wider precision is exact.

[IEEE Std 754-1985](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3O3Ys97VjtxYXBCY08wanNoZ1U)

Answer (score -1):

Quite funny, I wasn't able to find the IEEE 754 document that describes the standard. I guess that such conversions are not part of the "formal" standard, and they are left to the implementation (I may be wrong here).

Information-wise, there is no reason to lose information by the conversion 32bit->64bit->32bit. If performed correctly, the conversion should return exactly the original value.

Checking a few edge cases (using the calculators of http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/64bit.html) show this is indeed the case. It shouldn't be too difficult to write a program that goes over  all the 32bit values and verifies they convert back correctly. Ignoring the NaNs, this shouldn't even take that long.

Comment: Kahan played important role in creation of the standard. here is his paper http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/IEEE754.PDF  yes - it has no more then 2^32 states.

Comment: @Kaponir, how exactly would you go about storing more than 2^32 states in a 4 byte variable :=?

Comment: i'm not going to store more then 2^32 states.

Comment: @Kaponir thanks, I saw this paper - but this is "lecture notes" and not the final standard, right?

Comment: @Ran G. right - I just have no anything better.

Comment: @RanG. You couldn't find the standard because IEEE wants you to buy it :) It's like the standard on the C programming language and many others standards.

Comment: @AntonTrunov Interesting. I had in mind that standards, like Patents, are available to the public.

Comment: One notable exception that I'm aware of is the ECMA standards: "Ecma Standards and Technical Reports are made available as download to all interested persons or organizations, free of charge in PDF format" (taken from [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/index.html))